# View loses its grants when modifying

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Is it normal for an oracle view to loose all its grants when modifying the source SQL?
I am using SQL Developer if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you don't have "grants" - "grant" is an operation. You have "roles" and "privileges".

Second, views have neither roles nor privileges themselves - schemas do have. Basically, a self-descriptive command is: `grant select on view_1 to schema_1`.

Third, schemas do not lose their privileges if you create **or replace** your view. Here's a quick sample:

```
11:03:07 @> conn system/sys@oars_sandbox                                                                                                                            
Connected.                                                                                                                                                          
11:03:15 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> create user test1 identified by test1;                                                                                                

User created.                                                                                                                                                       

11:03:39 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> create user test2 identified by test2;                                                                                                

User created.                                                                                                                                                       

11:03:48 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> create view test1.view1 as select * from dual;                                                                                        

View created.                                                                                                                                                       

11:04:03 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> grant select on test1.view1 to test2;                                                                                                 

Grant succeeded.                                                                                                                                                    

11:04:15 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> select grantee, owner, table_name, privilege, grantor from dba_tab_privs where grantee = 'TEST2';                                     

GRANTEE                        OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                     PRIVILEGE                                GRANTOR                       
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- ------------------------------
TEST2                          TEST1                          VIEW1                          SELECT                                   TEST1                         

11:05:13 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> create or replace view test1.view1 as select * from dual;                                                                             

View created.                                                                                                                                                       

11:05:24 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> select grantee, owner, table_name, privilege, grantor from dba_tab_privs where grantee = 'TEST2';                                     

GRANTEE                        OWNER                          TABLE_NAME                     PRIVILEGE                                GRANTOR                       
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------- ------------------------------
TEST2                          TEST1                          VIEW1                          SELECT                                   TEST1
```

However, it is quite possible that SQL developer invokes `drop view` first instead of `create or replace`. In this case, your privileges are automatically removed.

```
11:05:26 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> drop view test1.view1;                                                                            

View dropped.                                                                                                                   

11:10:21 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> select grantee, owner, table_name, privilege, grantor from dba_tab_privs where grantee = 'TEST2'; 

no rows selected                                                                                                                

11:10:24 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> create or replace view test1.view1 as select * from dual;                                         

View created.                                                                                                                   

11:10:26 SYSTEM@oars_sandbox> select grantee, owner, table_name, privilege, grantor from dba_tab_privs where grantee = 'TEST2'; 

no rows selected
```